# Python image characters

Tags: python

How do you get the characters for a print statement like this? It is done using a function of the keyboard. I've tried searching and I can't find anything.

print("⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙◤")

Comment: If it is "a function of the keyboard" then it either comes free™ with your OS, or, it is a special function from your keyboard driver, or it is a special function from the selected input method, or it is a function in the software that you are using (and you mistake the actions from the *software* for ones made by the *keyboard*).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr)

```
print(repr("▲"))
```

output:

```
'\xe2\x96\xb2'
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the repr function.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the corresponding character by converting this string into python list ...

char_list = "⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙◤"
print list(char_list) # it will return character for above image..

Here how i achieved,

```
>>> c = "⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙▲⊙◤"
>>> list(c)
['\xe2', '\x8a', '\x99', '\xe2', '\x96', '\xb2', '\xe2', '\x8a', '\x99', '\xe2', '\x96', '\xb2', '\xe2', '\x8a', '\x99', '\xe2', '\x96', '\xb2', '\xe2', '\x8a', '\x99', '\xe2', '\x96', '\xb2', '\xe2', '\x8a', '\x99', '\xe2', '\x96', '\xb2', '\xe2', '\x8a', '\x99', '\xe2', '\x96', '\xb2', '\xe2', '\x8a', '\x99', '\xe2', '\x97', '\xa4']
>>> print "'\xe2\x8a\x99'"
'⊙'
>>>
```

Should combine 3 list elements  and try .. you will get the solution.